# Forking a process for simple shell

Tags: c, shell

I am writing a simple shell that needs to execute certain commands for a school assignment.  I've been mainly running the commands through the use of the system command.  However the assignment has a requirement that I'm not sure how to write or test:

Your shell should implement each command by forking a new process and overlaying the child process with the requested function. The parent process should wait for the command to finish before continuing unless the command is followed up with a “&” character.

Here is a snippet of my code for the "clear" command:

```
void processLine(  const char * const s ) {

   const char * const clrStr = "clr";
   const int cLen    = strlen(clrStr);
   const int cVal    = strncmp(s, clrStr, cLen);

   if (!cVal) {
        char * locator = strchr(s, '&');
        if (locator != NULL) {
           fork();
        }
        system("clear");
   }
}
```

Would this work?  I'm not sure how to make the parent process wait for the command to finish.

Comment: No, that doesn't do what is asked.  To '[overlay] the child process', you need to invoke an `exec*` function, but only do it in the child.

Comment: @WilliamPursell so how do I specify the child process versus the parent process?  Do you have any links I can read from?  My professor is not very good at explaining this.

Comment: There are lots of resources available!  `fork` returns 0 in the child, non-zero in the parent.  Typically, you check the return value.  In the child, call exec.  In the parent, conditionally call `wait`.